# Python behave step definitions not implemented

Tags: python, cucumber, python-behave

I am currently attempting to learn cucumber tests in Python with behave. Every time I have an error message that states my tests are undefined. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

my test.feature

```
Feature: Python integration


  Scenario: Cucumber Tests
    Given I have a new "DVD" in my cart
      And I have a new "BOOK" in my cart
    When I click on "hello"
    Then I should see "success"
```

my test.py

```
from behave import *


@given('I have a new {item} in my cart')
def step_impl(context, item):
    print("The item is: {}".format(item))


@when('I click on {link}')
def step_impl(context, link):
    print("I am clicking the link: {}".format(link))


@then('I should see {txt}')
def step_impl(context, txt):
    if txt not in ['success', 'error']:
        raise Exception("Unexpected text passed in.")

    print("Checking if I see the '{}' text".format(txt))
    print("PASS. I see the '{}' text".format(txt))
```

When I run behave I get the following output

```
Feature: Python integration # test.feature:2

  Scenario: Cucumber Tests              # test.feature:5
    Given I have a new "DVD" in my cart # None
    And I have a new "BOOK" in my cart  # None
    When I click on "hello"             # None
    Then I should see "success"         # None


Failing scenarios:
  test.feature:5  Cucumber Tests

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 4 undefined
Took 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Guessing here as not familiar with behave, the {DVD} and others should be replaced by "{text}"

Comment: No, I am not familiar with it, which is why I said "I am attempting to learn it". I was under the impression that the {DVD} and others where values that are passed into the parameters in the test.py {item}.

Comment: I mentioned that I am not familiar with python-behave...

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you where saying I was not familiar, not that you where not. My mistake. Anyway I figured out the answer, the test.py needs to be in a separate steps folder. Which is odd because PyCharm automatically generated mine, (you would think it would place it in an appropriate spot). Thanks @Grasshopper :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error it´s in the "success" quotes:

Feature:

```
...
- Then I should see "success"
...
```

Step implementation:

```
...
@then('I should see {txt}')
def step_impl(context, txt):
    if txt not in ['success', 'error']:
...
```

It should be:
Feature:

```
...
- Then I should see success
...
```

Or change the step implementation to:

```
...
@then('I should see {txt}')
def step_impl(context, txt):
    if txt not in ['"success"', 'error']:
...
```

The error is in the quotes used in "success". The step implementation use the text: "success" (including the quotes) and assigne it to the txt variable and so, in the if statement, txt is NOT equal to success without the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please can you add some formatting to make it more readable?

Comment: Formatted! Sorry about it ;)